# How to implement email validation on admin form in Magento2

Tags: validation, admin, magento2, email-validation

I want to use email validation in admin form of my custom module. I've seen core module but couldn't get exact idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is Model's issue. Only model knows how your data should look like. You describe your data fields in model, so you should describe validation rules for this fields in the same place.

It seems to be obvious for me, but I'd gladly listen to opponents.
 put database validation in the Model (assuming it's a db model) and http data validation in the controller. Xss filtering, for example, does not pertain to the Model. it pertains to the Controller in input and to the View in output

Comment: your answer doesn't seems relevant to Magento 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
You can also validate the 'email' text field by adding a class ['validate-email'] in your form

$fieldset->addField(
    'email',
    'text',
    [
        'name' => 'email', 
        'label' => __('Email'), 
        'title' => __('Email'), 
        'required' => true, 
        'class' => 'validate-email'
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by myself, I used PHP email validation in the save controller.